# android studio - captura fotos de cámara volcadas

Tags: android-studio

estoy haciendo un formulario de registro en la cual al momento de abrir la cámara y capturar la foto para imagen de perfil sale volcada a la derecha, hay alguna forma de solucionar esto, quiero que cuando se tome captura de la foto y la tenga que cargar al ImageView conserve su posición.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.formulario_registro_foto);

    initVariables();

    initComponent();

    setOnClickListener();
}

void initVariables(){

}

void initComponent(){
    buttonSiguiente = findViewById(R.id.btnSiguiente);
    imageViewFotoPerfil = findViewById(R.id.imageViewFotoPerfil);
    imageButtonCamara = findViewById(R.id.imgbtnCamara);
}

void setOnClickListener(){
    imageButtonCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                //Verifica Permisos para android 6.0+
                if(!checkExternalStoragePermission()){
                    return;
                }
            }

            contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "My Imagen");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

            intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
        }
    });

    buttonSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            intent = new Intent(Formulario_registro_foto.this, Formulario_registro_password.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch (requestCode){
        case PICTURE_RESULT:
            if(requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT){
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    try{
                        thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        imageViewFotoPerfil.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        //Obtiene la ruta dond se encuentra guardada la imagen
                        imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String [] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

private boolean checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if(permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    }
    else{
        Log.i("Mensaje","Se tiene permiso para leer!");
        return true;
    }
    return  false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira, puedes implementar este método:

```
private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    img.recycle();
    return rotatedImg;
}
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu código pues respuestas que son solo scripts se consideran de baja calidad, explica como esto resuelve el problema

Comment: genial, me funciono bien, pero ahora surgió otro problema, como controlo cuando la imagen se toma con la cámara en posición horizontal?. Cuando la tomo en posición vertical funciona bien, el método que dijiste rota la imagen, pero cuando es en posición horizontal la imagen se voltea de cabeza.